# How to get the CNContact from a birthday EKEvent

Tags: objective-c, ios9, ekevent, cncontact

From iOS 9, the EKEvent property **birthdayPersonID** is deprecated.

How can I get the CNContact associated with a birthday event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try using `birthdayPersonID`, it will produce a warning that says:

> warning: 'birthdayPersonID' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - Use birthdayContactIdentifier instead

So, use `birthdayContactIdentifier`.

Comment: Thanks! I was looking at the doc and the new property is not yet there.

Comment: Yeah, sometimes you just have to look at the headers. That's where I found it.